# If else alternative for a conditional operator filter in a predicate?

Tags: c#, lambda, ternary-operator

After a long search i have my first question.
I have this piece of code:

```
var strings = new MyStringList { "orange", "APPLE", "grape", "pear" };
foreach (var item in strings.Where(s => s.Length == 5))
{
  txtLog.WriteLine(item);
}
```

And a public class:

```
public class MyStringList : List<string>
{
  public IEnumerable<string> Where(Predicate<string> filter)
  {
    return this.Select(s => filter(s) ? s.ToUpper() : s);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite the return statement in an If Else construction?

I came to something like this, only the if gives an error:

```
if (this.Select(s=> filter(s)))
{
  return this.Select(s => s.ToUpper());
}
else
{
  return this.Select(s => s);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `filter` works on a single item, you have to iterate through your collection first. During iteration there is no longer any need to use `Select()` instead you use `yield return` to dynamically return an iterator.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Where(Predicate<string> filter)
{
    foreach (var s in this)
    {
        if (filter(s))
            yield return s.ToUpper();
        else
            yield return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm shocked yet nobody write a comment like `+1 for yield`